# how to select event by class in prototype

Tags: jquery, class, events, prototypejs

in jQuery. i am invoking an event by class. how do you do same in Prototype.

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  var element = $(this);
  var Id = element.attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$$('.button').observe('click', respondToClick);

function respondToClick(event) {
   var element = event.element();
   var Id = element.id;
}
```

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event

Comment: You've got some messed up quotation marks in there, and I think you mean $$(), not $().

Answer (score 1):

```
Event.observe($$('.button'), 'click', function(e) {
    // ...
});
```